# I cannot set text of my Custom Text Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to make a custom TextField (KSTextField). I inherited my text field from UITextField. As you can see my KSTextField.h file below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UITextField.h>

@interface KSTextField : UITextField {}

@end
```

In my KSTextField.m i tried to set a dummy text attribute. But it doesn't work. Is super.text usage wrong?

My main purpose is, making a custom UITextField that only allows for upper case characters which is needed for my project.

```
#import "KSTextField.h"

@implementation KSTextField

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    super.text = @"help";
    return self;
}

- (void)textFieldDidChangeForKS:(KSTextField *)textField {
    self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
    NSString *textToUpper = [textField.text uppercaseString];
    [self setText:textToUpper];
}

@end
```

And also mine ViewController.h is below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KSTextField.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 


@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet KSTextField *txtKsName;


@end
```

Here's my ViewController.m which i want to set my KSTextField.text

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.txtKsName = [[KSTextField alloc] init];

}
```

Delegate events do not solve my issue. Because i'll add much more features later. It will be my custom textfield thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: you're doing it wrong! You don't have to subclass to allow uppercase characters only. Use a `UITextFieldDelegate`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Using the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method, you can say whether on not the character typed is allowed to be added to the box.

Try something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters
{
    NSCharacterSet *blockedCharacters = [[[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] invertedSet] retain];
    return ([characters rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharacters].location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Comment: Where should i use that? 
On my ViewController.m ? 

I did it sub class because some of my text inputs needed to allow uppercase only. Not only that one. And also not everyone.

Comment: Also In my KSTextField.m i tried to set a dummy text attribute as you can see the code. But it doesn't work. Is super.text usage wrong?

Comment: There are a lot of resources out there about using `UITextViewDelegate` that explain better than I can, like [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uitextview_uitextviewdelegate_2/), for example. I would definitely use the delegate instead of subclassing though, because it is much easier.

Comment: The reason why i want a subclass is that I'll add probably more features/behaviours to my class and instead of using UITextfield in my project, I want to use my own class to prevent code duplication for every UITextbox I add.. So creating a subclass is still the wrong approach??

Comment: You can use the same delegate for as many `UITextFields`s as you want, so if validating input is your only concern, then yes, subclassing is the wrong approach.

Comment: No it is not my only concern. I'm sure that i'll add much more custom features later. So if you guide me on creating a subclass it will be more helpful for me...

Thanks for patience and help :)

Comment: What are your other concerns?

Comment: Don't know yet. We're on kind of preparation process for now. i want to do that as generic as possible. Because i'm pretty sure that i have to change the look of control later. And also i'll need much more validations. I don't want to duplicate event codes for every screens.

Comment: Did you try `self.text` instead of `super.text`?

Comment: Yes. First i tried self.text. Then i saw a super.text in an example code.

Comment: Are you seeing the text field at all, or just the text isn't showing up?

Comment: when i debug it i saw that the text has been set in the subclass. But i cannot see the text on my main viewcontrol.

So i see the text field. but i dont see the text that i've set on the subclasses init method.